# How to check if div contains certain text or not?

Tags: javascript, html

I added some text to div like this:

```
document.getElementById("" + choice).innerHTML += "e";
```

But later in my script I want to check if that div contains my text. I have tried the below code:

```
if (document.getElementById("" + choice).innerHTML === "e") {
    alert('yep!');
}
```

But it doesn't work, I don't get the "yep!' alert. How do I fix it?

Comment: What was it's innerHTML before?

Comment: You are using `innerHTML += "e";`thus adding something to the HTML

Comment: `+= "e"` implies content was already there, whereas you’re testing for `=== ‘e’`, exactly-equal to ‘e’.

Comment: @LucaKiebel it was empty

Answer (score 4):

You are appending the text using `+=` operator and not completely setting it to `e`.

Thus, if the `innerHTML` was `foo` it would be `fooe`.

What you might want to do is:

```
if ((document.getElementById("" + choice).innerHTML).indexOf("e") !== -1) {
    alert('yep!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use :

```js
if (document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML.includes("e")) {
    alert('yep!');
}
```

```html
<div id="hello">hello world</div>
```

Because in this code:

```
document.getElementById("" + choice).innerHTML += "e";
```

you are adding `"e"` to innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

use document.getElementById("" + choice).innerHTML.contains("e")

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
var myContent = "e"

document.getElementById("" + choice).innerHTML += myContent;

if (document.getElementById("" + choice).innerHTML.includes(myContent)) {
    alert('yep!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did intend to use the `+=` operator instead of `=`. You might have whitespace in your div. You can use the trim function to get rid of that like in this snippet.

If you change the operator to `=` you can still use the check without trim.

```js
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "e";
console.log('innerHTML value: "' + document.getElementById("test").innerHTML + '"');
if (document.getElementById("test").innerHTML === "e") {
    console.log('passed');
}
if (document.getElementById("test").innerHTML.trim() === "e") {
    console.log('passed with trim');
}
```

```html
<div id="test"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

+= means concat new value to current value. i guess if you want to replace the div's innerHTML to "e", youshould replace "+=" in

```
document.getElementById("" + choice).innerHTML += "e";
```

to "=".
else if you'd like to append string to div's innerHTML, you should replace '===' in

```
if (document.getElementById("" + choice).innerHTML === "e") {
    alert('yep!');
}
```

to includes function.